# Case expression different in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby

This is an example code from a book. I assume it's for Ruby 1.8.

```
    birthyear = 1986
    generation = case birthyear
        when 1946...1963: "Baby boomer"
        when 1964...1976: "Generation X"
        when 1977...2012: "new generation"
        else nil
    end

    puts generation
```

I ran it on Ruby 1.9, and got this error message:

```
    Untitled 2.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
    when 1946...1963: "Baby boomer"
                     ^
Untitled 2.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting $end
    when 1964...1976: "Generation X"
```

How should I change this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There was a change in the syntax between 1.8.x and 1.9.x where the `:` is now no longer allowed:

```
 birthyear = 1986
 generation = case birthyear
   when 1946...1963
     "Baby boomer"
   when 1964...1976
     "Generation X"
   when 1977...2012
     "new generation"
   else
     nil
   end

 puts generation
```

Technically `:` has been replaced by `then` but that's an optional keyword if you use a newline. It's a bit of a hassle to go and track down cases where you've used the old syntax, so hopefully searching for `case` is close enough.

Comment: "There was a change in the syntax between 1.8.x and 1.9.x where the : is now no longer allowed" – The `:` was *never* allowed. It was *never* part of the official syntax of Ruby. It was *never* documented. It was added to MRI's parser for reasons unknown and it was left in for fear that a change to the parser might break something, but Matz has *always* made it *very* clear that `:` in `case` and `if` expressions is *not* part of the syntax, that it *must not* be used and that it *will* be removed from the MRI parser in the future, which Koichi Sasada finally did in YARV.

Comment: I started using them in 1.8.x quite religiously as they seemed to be the "standard", even if de-facto rather than official. It was a rude awakening when 1.9.x pulled support. At least I was able to make a Ruby regexp to fix the broken code at the time.

Answer (score 10):

According to the 3rd edition of the [PickAxe](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9), it is intentional.

p 125, Case Expressions :

> "Ruby 1.8 allowed you to use a colon character in place of the `then`
>   keyword. This is no longer supported."

example, with `then` and no newlines:

```
birthyear = 1986
generation = case birthyear
  when 1946...1963 then "Baby boomer"
  when 1964...1976 then "Generation X"
  when 1977...2012 then "new generation"
  else nil
end

puts generation
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just replace the colons with *semi*-colons.

Just tested this example:

```
birthyear = 1986
generation = case birthyear
    when 1946...1963; "Baby boomer"
    when 1964...1976; "Generation X"
    when 1977...2012; "new generation"
    else nil
end

puts generation
```

The semi-colon works exactly the same as a new line in this context, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your puts

```
puts generation  # not "gemeration"
```

also try something like this :

```
score = 70

result = case score
  when 0..40 then "Fail"
  when 41..60 then "Pass"
  when 61..70 then "Pass with Merit"
  when 71..100 then "Pass with Distinction"
  else "Invalid Score"
end

puts result
```

Comment: Indent code with four spaces for proper formatting, or use back ticks for inline code.

Answer (score -2):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
score = 70
result = case score
   when 0..40 then "Fail"
   when 41..60 then "Pass"
   when 61..70 then "Pass with Merit"
   when 71..100 then "Pass with Distinction"
   else "Invalid Score"
end
puts result
```