# ruby syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svn

I've recently updated ruby from 1.8.7.374 to 2.1.2p95 and I have a svn post-commit script which was working fine but now it fails.

```
changes=`#{svnlook} diff #{repo} -r #{rev}`
body << "<pre>"
changes.each do |top_line|
top_line.split("\n").each do |line|
color = case
  when line =~ /^Modified: / || line =~ /^=+$/ || line =~ /^@@ /: 'gray'
  when line =~ /^-/ 'red:'
  when line =~ /^\+/ 'blue:'
  else "black"
  end
  body << %Q{<font style="color:#{color}">#{CGI.escapeHTML(line)}</font>    <br/>\n}
  end
  end
  body << "</pre>"
```

Here's the errors I get:

```
    [root@dev hooks]# ruby -c post-commit
post-commit:66: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or     ',' or ';' or '\n'
...ne =~ /^=+$/ || line =~ /^@@ /: 'gray'
...                               ^
post-commit:67: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting    keyword_end
  when line =~ /^-/ 'red:'
      ^
post-commit:67: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting     keyword_end
      when line =~ /^-/ 'red:'
                     ^
post-commit:68: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting     keyword_end
      when line =~ /^\+/ 'blue:'
      ^
post-commit:68: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting     keyword_end
      when line =~ /^\+/ 'blue:'
                      ^
post-commit:69: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting     keyword_end
      else "black"
      ^
post-commit:65: warning: assigned but unused variable - color
post-commit:18: warning: assigned but unused variable - saddress
post-commit:20: warning: assigned but unused variable - sendmail
post-commit:73: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-    input
```

Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

Comment: Error in line: `when line =~ /^Modified: / || line =~ /^=+$/ || line =~ /^@@ /: 'gray'`, as error message mentioned. Just remove `:` after `/^@@ /`.

Comment: Thanks, Atul ! It worked.

Comment: I've added above comment as an answer. Kindly accept, as it  resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby 1.9, `case` expressions don't allow a colon anymore (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305565/766783)).

To fix it, change your code to

```
color = case
when line =~ /^Modified: / || line =~ /^=+$/ || line =~ /^@@ /
  'gray'
when line =~ /^-/
  'red:'
when line =~ /^\+/
  'blue:'
else
  "black"
end
```

Comment: The colon was never allowed. It was added to the parser as an experimental feature, but it was never officially documented, and in fact matz has said multiple times that it's only an accidental leftover and *must not* be used under any circumstances, because it is simply not part of the Ruby language.

Answer (score 0):

Error in line: `when line =~ /^Modified: / || line =~ /^=+$/ || line =~ /^@@ /: 'gray'`, as error message mentioned. Just remove `:` after `/^@@ /`.